# Openshift on-premise deployment by in house Devops teams advisable?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, on-premises-instances

For a medium-sized enterprise, we want to deploy RH Openshift (or any other K8 platform) - on-premise - due to security related policies

- What are the risks associated with on-premise Openshift (or K8 in general) setup?
- Is it better to have Openshift (or K8) installed by the vendor (in the case of Openshift, its RH) or by an in-house DevOps teams with K8 certifications can usually do it?
- What are the other factors I should consider before making such a decision

Answer (score 2):

Risk of k8's on premise: Maintenance. On top of your existing workload to manage the servers you now have to patch k8's as well, while ensuring you don't bring the whole thing down. Security, who can call the servers. Firewalls. Auth etc etc. Usually these things are much easier on a managed k8s.

vendor or inhouse: Look, You can do it in house if you want. But if you don't get people who are on the ball and gods at k8's, you're gonna have a rough time. The advantage of going with a vendor is the people problem is their problem. They have to ensure they can bring the necessary skills to the table. Another point: DevOps is Developer Operations. Not k8's managers. You need an SRE (Site Reliability Engineer).

Other considerations: Cost.